# Should there be a Bitcoin equivalent of Tux?

Tags: marketing

Many questions on this forum center on the idea of getting Bitcoin to go mainstream. One mechanism that the Linux team employed for their distros was the idea of a mascot - the Linux penguin, Tux (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux).

So should Bitcoin have an equivalent? And if you think so, what would you suggest and why?

Comment: I think that this question is not very appropriate for our Q&A format. There is not on real answer to this. A discussion forum would be a better place to gather ideas.

Comment: If you start a forum thread on that, please paste a link here;).

Comment: Created a forum thread for this: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=49289.0

Comment: And it's a good thing I'm not a moderator there, because that thread is a duplicate of [this one](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=24680.0) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allie the Apaca !
http://www.livanti-alpacas.com/images/photos/alpaca_horizon.jpg

A lot of the early bitcoin coverage mentioned the fact that you buy alpaca socks so I think the alpaca should be the bitcoin mascot. Obvious names are Al and Allie. I think Allie is cuter.

Comment: ... and a Bitcoin badge... could be on to something here

Answer (score 0):

As the first thing that one can associate with the word "Bitcoin" is a coin, one should probably go in that direction. Since coins are not very animate in themselves and anthropomorphizing them would probably look silly, probably something that has a strong correlation with a coin is the way to go. One can think of materials - gold and silver, specific faces from the coins (which is too local to consider), and people dealing with coins and money - bankers, tax-collectors, those figures don't really have any good connotations in general. There is one more group of people that are associated with coins - pirates, which whereas can have negative connotations (digital piracy), are also considered positive in some manners (Pirates of the Caribbean, etc.). So I think we should be considering some pirate with a chest full of Bitcoins.

Alternatively, there are also other more fantasy creatures people associate with coins or precious metals - leprechauns, dwarves, and the like. Whereas those don't have much negative connotations, their positive connotations aren't very prevalent either, so I would stick with pirates.

Comment: Pirates seem to be getting a bad name in the press these days: music downloads, Somalia. But then they are also associated with liberty and freedom from authority. As a mascot, I think it might be too charged - or I might be reading too much into it.

Comment: Oh boy, please no pirates! Pirates are not positive in any way whatsoever.

Comment: "Join Bitcoin and have your coins stolen by pirates with big chests of Bitcoin!" comes to mind... maybe that's just me also though..

Comment: How about "do what you want, 'cos a pirate is free?" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jbq_1Wy70rE

Answer (score 0):

Sure ! bitcoin need a mascot !

+1 for the alpaca, good idea

a spider could also be a good idea, typically some kind of collaborative spiders ( most spiders work alone but there are also some small ones who work together to build gigantic webs )

Comment: Hmm, not so sure about a spider - arachnaphobia is quite common and could get confused with Halloween